# Android Video Processing Using Vertex shader and Fragment Shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am working on a project that is based on Video Processing. I want to add a filter on Video like Glitch Effect, Moving Videos, Image Moving, Scaling, etc. But I want to achieve by using vertex shader and fragment shader. Does anyone have an idea about Vertex GLSL integration with Android?

I want to achieve video encoder like this:

https://youtu.be/KCab4czHN4c